# In tensorflow, how to make any entry >0.5 becomes 1 in a tensor?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

For example, `a = [0,0.2,0.8]`

I want to make it `a = [0,0.2,1]`

I searched for a long time, but I only found `tf.bool_mask` which can only get a bool tensor and I dont know what to do next.

I know at least in numpy, its very easy, but how to do it in tensorflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using the [`tf.where()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where) and [`tf.ones_like()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/ones_like) ops:

```
a = tf.constant([0.0, 0.2, 0.8])

result = tf.where(a > 0.5, tf.ones_like(a), a)  # result is [0.0, 0.2, 1.0]
```